# Форматирование данных в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как можно сформировать, если `А`, `B`, `C` - множества(`set()`)?

На это компилятор ругается:

```
def check():
    if label_1["text"] == "":
        label_1["text"] = "1) %d - %d = %d" % (self.A, self.B, self.A - self.B)
        label_1.grid()
    elif label_2["text"] == "":
        label_2["text"] = "2) %d & %d = %d" % (self.B, self.A, self.B & self.A)
        label_2.grid()
    elif label_3["text"] == "":
        label_3["text"] = "3) (%d - %d) | (%d & %d) = %d" % (self.A, self.B, self.B, self.A,
                                                             (self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A))
        label_3.grid()
    elif label_4["text"] == "":
        label_4["text"] = "4) ((%d - %d) | (%d & %d) ) \ (%d | %d)  = %d" % \
                          (self.A, self.B, self.B, self.A, self.C, self.B,
                           ((self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A)) - (self.C | self.B))
        label_4.grid()
    elif label_5["text"] == "":
        label_5["text"] = "Result: %s" % str(((self.A - self.B) | (self.B & self.A)) - (self.C | self.B))
        label_5.grid()
```

Comment: Какой трейсбек? Добавьте код ошибки в вопрос

Comment: Обязательно ли нужно форматировать?

Comment: уже разобрался, спасибо

Comment: Замените `%d` (форматирование аргумента как целого числа) на `%s` (форматирование как строки). Вообще не очень понятно, зачем вы от более гибкого `format` и фигурных скобок перешли к форматированию через `%`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Начиная с Python 3.6 можно использовать [`Formatted string literals` AKA `f-string`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
In [30]: A = set([1,2,3])

In [31]: B = set([2,3,4])

In [32]: f'{A} - {B} = {A-B}'
Out[32]: '{1, 2, 3} - {2, 3, 4} = {1}'
```

альтернатива:

```
In [35]: '{} - {} = {}'.format(A, B, A-B)
Out[35]: '{1, 2, 3} - {2, 3, 4} = {1}'
```